# Double integral; limits and variable exchange

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am struggling to figure out the correct way of calculating certain integrals of this nature, i.e. more complicated limits and functions:

$$\int_{x=0}^1 \left( \int_{y=\sqrt[3]{x}}^1 \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1+y^8}}\right) dx $$

Typically I'd try to re-write the limits and/or a variable change so it is easier to perform the integration. However, I am struggling and I can't seem to find any help in my textbook and class material.

The idea I had would be to rewrite the limits to $ \; 0 \le x \le y^3 \; , \; 0 \le y \le 1 \;$ and first integrate $\; \int_{x=0}^{y^3}dx \;$ and then $ \int dy \;$, but I seem to get stuck on the next step. I.e when.

$$ \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{([x]_0^{y^3})}{\sqrt{1+y^8}}dy = \int_{y=0}^1 \frac{y^3}{\sqrt{1+y^8}}dy $$

What would my next steps be and how? I would like to say that a variable exchange would be in order, e.g. $ u=y^4 \Rightarrow \frac{du}{dy}= 4y^3 \; $ but I can't figure it out. The answer in my book does not give any advice or guidance.

This is my first post, so I do ask for your forgiveness if there is something wrong!

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing great — you got the hard part, namely, changing the limits. (I always suggested to my students that they sketch the region to get that right.) Following up on your substitution, you have
$$\int_0^1 \frac{y^3\,dy}{\sqrt{1+y^8}} = \int_0^1 \frac{\frac14 du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}.$$
There are various ways to do this integral, but the most obvious is the trig substitution $u=\tan\theta$, $du=\sec^2\theta\,d\theta$, so you end up with
$$\frac14\int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sec^2\theta\,d\theta}{\sec\theta} = \frac14\int_0^{\pi/4} \sec\theta\,d\theta,$$ which I leave it to you to finish.

Comment: I wish it was more obvious to me! That is a substitution I couldn't see.. I was hoping to get $ \int \frac{1}{{1+u^2}} = [\tan^{-1}(u)] \;$ with a substitution but the square root caught me. Thank you much!